# How can I change the related site for a chatroom after the room is created?

Tags: discussion, chat, area-51

We have a chatroom for the [Korean Language Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language?referrer=_bGLWL4a0nyN5qIsOP5VxA2) at Area51 at

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30769/korean-language-discussion-room-commit-stage

During creation it got associated with TeX stackexchange as a related chatroom

How can I change this association? I would like it to associate with Area51 itself, or with Travel stackexchange.

Comment: You need a TeX moderator or an SE employee to change this now

Comment: the chatroom was just created a few hours ago and doesnt have any activity yet, so would it be better to just delete the room and start all over?

Comment: but then again, I am not sure how to delete this room either

Comment: You can't delete a room